# Filter array by keys and populate new multi-dimensional array from mutated keys and original values

Tags: php, arrays, regex, key, filtering

I need to extract data from elements with keys that start with `foo.` from the below array:

```
[
    'name' => 'Bar',
    'location' => 'Baz',
    'foo.2021-02-01' => '50000.00',
    'foo.2021-03-01' => '50000.00',
    'foo.2021-04-01' => '50000.00',
    'foo.2021-05-01' => '',
]
```

After identifying qualifying keys, I need to create a new indexed array of associative rows using the date substring from the original keys like so:

```
[
    ['date' => '2021-02-01', 'value' => '50000.00'],
    ['date' => '2021-03-01', 'value' => '50000.00'],
    ['date' => '2021-04-01', 'value' => '50000.00'],
    ['date' => '2021-05-01', 'value' => ''],
]
```

I've been able to extract the keys like so:

```
$keys = array_keys($theData[0]);
foreach ( $keys as $key ) {
    if ( preg_match( '/foo.*/', $key ) ) {
        $line = explode('.', $key);
        $item[]['name'] = $line[1];
    }
}
```

but I'm losing the values.

I then tried looping through the array manually and rebuilding the desired outcome, but the keys will change so I don't know how future-proof that would be.

Is there a wildcard approach I can take to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost had it:

```
<?php
$theData = [
    'name' => 'Bar',
    'location' => 'Baz',
    'foo.2021-02-01' => '50000.00',
    'foo.2021-03-01' => '50000.00',
    'foo.2021-04-01' => '50000.00',
    'foo.2021-05-01' => ''
];

$item = [];

// No need for array_keys(), foreach() can already do this
foreach( $theData as $key => $value )
{
    // check if the key starts with foo.
    // Regular expressions are heavy; if you'd like then substitute with:
    // if ( substr( $key, 0, 4 ) === 'foo.' )
    if ( preg_match( '/^foo\\./', $key ) )
    {
        // foo. is 4 chars long so substring from the fourth index till the end
        $item[] = [
            'date' => substr( $key, 4 ),
            'value' => $value
        ];
    }
}

var_dump( $item );
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2021-02-01"
    ["value"]=>
    string(8) "50000.00"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2021-03-01"
    ["value"]=>
    string(8) "50000.00"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2021-04-01"
    ["value"]=>
    string(8) "50000.00"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2021-05-01"
    ["value"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple loop, checking for the key starting with `foo.` and then a little code to replace `foo.` in the key with nothing will do the trick

### If you have PHP8 or >

```
$arr = [
    'name' => 'Bar',
    'location' => 'Baz',
    'foo.2021-02-01' => '50000.00',
    'foo.2021-03-01' => '50000.00',
    'foo.2021-04-01' => '50000.00',
    'foo.2021-05-01' => ''
];

$new = [];
foreach ($arr as $k => $v){
    if ( str_starts_with( $k , 'foo.' ) ) {
        $new[] = ['date' => str_replace('foo.', '', $k), 'value' => $v];
    }
}
print_r($new);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        ([date] => 2021-02-01, [value] => 50000.00)
    [1] => Array
        ([date] => 2021-03-01, [value] => 50000.00)
    [2] => Array
        ([date] => 2021-04-01, [value] => 50000.00)
    [3] => Array
        ([date] => 2021-05-01, [value] => )
)
```

### Alternatively, for PHP versions prior to PHP8

```
$new = [];
foreach ($arr as $k => $v){
    if ( strpos( $k , 'foo.') !== FALSE && strpos( $k , 'foo.') == 0 ) {
        $new[] = ['date' => str_replace('foo.', '', $k), 'value' => $v];
    }
}
```

Comment: I think "checking for the key starting with `foo.`" is a misstatement. This code checks for the **existence** of `foo.` anywhere in the key.

Comment: It's also unclear which functionality OP is seeking considering the fact that they are using the regex `/foo.*/` but their data only has it in the beginning so +1 for you ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I try and avoid the overhead of loading the regex engine if its not necessary

Comment: Yes, agreed. I commented on that in my answer as well. I was just pointing out that at this point we don't know if `str_contains()` is most correct or `str_starts_with()`...

Comment: Might be worth mentioning `str_starts_with` is available since PHP 8 and offering an alternative for PHP 7 (I doubt that the majority is already using 8).

Comment: @El_Vanja Everyone is trying to make my life more difficult today :) :) But when you are right, you are right ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using [str_starts_with](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-starts-with.php) and [explode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```php
$arr = [];
foreach ($theData as $k => $v){
  if (str_starts_with($k, "foo."))
    $arr[] = ["date" => explode(".", $k)[1], "value" => $v];
}
var_dump($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

`sscanf()` is an ideal function to call which will both check for qualifying strings and extract the desired trailing date value.  It doesn't use regex, but it does require a placeholder `%s` to target the date substring.  If a given string doesn't qualify, no element is pushed into the result array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/1kJFp)) ([without `compact()`](https://3v4l.org/UUOoZ))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (sscanf($key, 'foo.%s', $date)) {
        // $result[] = ['date' => $date, 'value' => $value];
        $result[] = compact(['date', 'value']); 
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

If you remove the optional technique of using `compact()`, this solution makes fewer function calls than all other answers on this page.

I would probably only use regex if I wanted to strengthen the validation for qualifying key strings. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/4aW7U))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (preg_match('~^foo\.\K\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$~', $key, $m)) {
        $result[] = ['date' => $m[0], 'value' => $value]; 
    }
}
var_export($result);
```